# Outlook mail signature script with with image (.vbs)

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, outlook, signature, watermark

I am actually working on a vbscript to generate the signature on Outlook, which should look like this;

[image]

All the data is being fetched successfully and the format seems okay, as I hae been using a table and placed the data in the corresponding cells to avoid overlapping and all.

Here is my code;

```
' Instantiation
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature
Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

Details = "Details Details Details Details Details Details Details Details"

' Add logo 
Set objRange = objDoc.Range()
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, 4, 2
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
objTable.Columns(0).Width = 900
objTable.Columns(1).Width = 100

' Full Name
objTable.Rows(1).Cells.Merge
objTable.Rows(1).Height = 5
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Color = RGB(15,0,250)
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Name = "Monotype Corsiva"
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Bold = true
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Size = 16 
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = strFirstName & " " &  strLastName 

' Title
objTable.Rows(2).Cells.Merge
objTable.Rows(2).Height = 5
objTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Font.Color = RGB(15,36,62)
objTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Font.Name = "Monotype Corsiva"
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Bold = true
objTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Font.Size = 12
objTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = strTitle

' Details
objTable.Rows(3).Cells.Merge
objTable.Rows(3).Height = 15
objTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Font.Color = RGB(15,36,62)
objTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Font.Size = 8 
objTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = Details  

' Images
objTable.Rows(4).Height = 15
If (strGender = "M") Then
    objTable.Cell(4, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture "C:\Scripts\Logon\Male.jpg"
Else
    objTable.Cell(4, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture "C:\Scripts\Logon\Female.jpg"
End if

' Logo
objTable.Cell(4, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture "C:\Scripts\Logon\logoSignatureNew.jpg"
objTable.Cell(4, 2).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2

objSelection.EndKey END_OF_STORY  
Set objSelection = objDoc.Range() 

objSignatureEntries.Add "Signature", objSelection
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Signature"

objDoc.Saved = true
objDoc.Close
objWord.Quit
```

The output, as of now, is as follows;
[image]

Can anyone please help me to add the balloon around the text? I don't know how we can add an image and `send to back` or use a sort of watermark.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Why do you remove the same question and re-create it back? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738125/outlook-mail-signature-script-vbs

Comment: Because I found part of the solution, that's where I've reached now and my only issue now is to place the balloon around. I hope its not you who votedown my post! I deleted the other post anyway since I had no answer for it!

Comment: Instead of deleting and recreating the post I'd suggest leaving the feedback what you have found so far.

Answer (score -1):

The Outlook look object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. Body - a raw text.
2. HTMLBody - an HTML markup.
3. The Word Editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body.

The last two can be used to get the job done. You can find all of them described in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article in MSDN.